# Show progress bar in curl without showing response content

Tags: bash, curl

Is there are way within Bash to hide the response body of a curl `GET` request whilst still showing a progress bar?

`--progress-bar` Shows a minified version of the default bar however still outputs everything.

Likewise with `--silent` which hides everything which is unhelpful for the volume of requests.

My current code is,

```
for i in $(cat scripts/urls.txt); do
    file="scripts/output.txt"
    content=$(curl --location --request GET $i -H 'Authorization: ...')
    "$content" >> $file
    cat $file
    sleep 5
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The progress bar is sent to stderr. The response is sent to stdout. To redirect and append the response to a file you could use the `>>` operator:

```sh
while read -r i; do
    file="scripts/output.txt"
    curl --location --request GET $i -H 'Authorization: ...' >> $file
    sleep 5
done < scripts/urls.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$ curl -X GET http://www.example.com > /dev/null
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  1256  100  1256    0     0  22445      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 22836
```

Comment: this will discard the content, from the example given it's obvious the content needs to be saved

Comment: @root This both discards, and logs the response. Both of which I am trying to avoid. Nevertheless, thanks for the answer.